# IOS - Justify UILabel like in the newspaper

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview

I'm trying to align my UILabel/UITextView like in the picture below.

Anyone got a lead how to justify the text that way.

[image]

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @jurgemaister it seems pretty specific. ibm123 wants to know how to justify text in a text view they way it's justified in the attached image. It's specific enough that madhu could answer it with one line of code.

Comment: try using a UITextView, I've not attempted it, but UILabel has loads of bugs in it.

Answer (score 8):

I have some trouble with `NSTextAlignementJustified` too.

You can achieve this with the use of NSAttributedString, by setting the alignment and by setting firstLineHeadIndent to something close to zero (why? hmmmm... well I don't know):

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyles.alignment                = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
paragraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent      = 0.001f;
NSString *stringTojustify                = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
NSDictionary *attributes                 = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles};
NSAttributedString *attributedString     = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringTojustify attributes:attributes];

CGFloat labelWidth = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.7f;
UILabel* myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.5f - labelWidth * 0.5f,
                                                             100,
                                                             labelWidth,
                                                             800)];
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
[myLabel sizeToFit];

[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the alignment of your `UILabel` to `NSTextAlignmentJustified`

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
```

Comment: @ibm123 your text view is definitely justified. Your label is probably centered: ```NSTextAlignmentCenter```

Answer (score 2):

Y. Bonafons thank you! Being new to Swift, it took me quite a while to use your code, so I'm typing that for Swift 2 here:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let labelWidth = CGFloat(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.7)

        let explanationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.5 - labelWidth * 0.5, 100, labelWidth, 800))

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 15

        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 10.0

        explanationLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum")

        let mutableAttrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: explanationLabel.attributedText!)

        mutableAttrStr.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttrStr.length))

        explanationLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        explanationLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        explanationLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        explanationLabel.attributedText = mutableAttrStr

        explanationLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.view.addSubview(explanationLabel)

    }

}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The perfect update solution is to used `NSMutableParagraphStyle` test on xCode 7 and iOS 9

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyles.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;      //justified text
        paragraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent = 1.0;
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles};
        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: YourString attributes: attributes];
        YourLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a little addition to the great answer of Y. Bonafons - you can achieve the same result by setting '[First Line Indent](http://s33.postimg.org/emvnbsmjz/Screen_Shot_2016_05_26_at_17_30_03.png)' via Interface Builder (checked on xCode 7.3.1).