# Center justify UILabel text?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to center-justify the text of my UILabel like the picture :

[image]

Sample of my code :

`myLabel.textAlignment = .Justified
myLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping`

The result I have :

[image]

Did I miss something ?

Comment: You could try to add a `NSMutableParagraphStyle` with `alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified` as an attribute to the `UILabel`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27548566/833816

It works by adding `paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0.001`

Full sample:

```swift
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .Justified
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0.001

let mutableAttrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: detailsLabel.attributedText)
mutableAttrStr.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttrStr.length))
myLabel.attributedText = mutableAttrStr
```

Comment: It worked for me but I had to add a `!` after `detailsLabel` and `attributedText` so the final code would be like this: `NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: detailsLabel!.attributedText!)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

Comment: The text is centered but not justified

Comment: That's what I was looking for!