# How to set UITextView alignment to justify and center?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, justify

I am trying to use text alignment center and justify

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 10
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
self.descriptionTextView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: myString) , attributes:attributes)
self.descriptionTextView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:17)
self.descriptionTextView.textAlignment = .Center
```

I want `.Center` and `.Justify` together!
somethings like this:

[image]

Can anybody give some code for this?

Comment: Try to use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754199/center-justify-uilabel-text

Comment: In Xcode also simply done by going to the right side of the screen when editing the storyboard. That might be easier for what you're trying to do. It's in the Attributes Inspector (the 4th tab).